# set bookmark with environment variable in vifm

Tags: vifm

In the vifmrc I tried to set a bookmark like

```
bmark! $home/tmp tmp
```

... but that doesnt seem to work.

What I get is a bookmark with the path `/location_where_i_was_when_setting_the_bookmark/$home/tmp` or `~/$home/tmp`

Is that a bug or expected behaviour, and if the latter **my question is**:
(how) can I set bookmarks with shell environment variables.

I also tried to set reset the environment variable in the vifmrc before assigning it but that didnt work

```
let &home=$home
bmark! $home/tmp tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:bmark` command doesn't expand environment variables as of v0.12.

For `$HOME` you can use `~` which is expanded.

For others try adding [`:execute`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Aexecute) like this:

```
execute 'bmark!' $wtmp 'tmp'
```